# How can I use the "Windows Live Call Button" on my headphone to answer a call with Skype?

Tags: windows, skype, headphones, windows-live-messenger

[Webcams and headphones from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/windowslivedevices/marketplace/pages/en-us/default.htm) (like for example the LifeChat ZX-6000, in my case) have a button which can be used only with Windows Live Messenger, to answer a call.

[image: zx 6000]

There is no option provided to configure it so that it would launch a program, or work in another communicator, in the given drivers.

Is there a way to make it work with [Skype](http://www.skype.com/), so that I can answer a call by pressing this button? Maybe there are other drivers?

Comment: *It took me some time to find this little program, so I thought that I would share on SU, in case someone else needs it.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small utility created by Jonathan Kay named [Skype Call Button](http://messengergeek.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!E3785B1281BBDA1!2709.entry), which can be used in this purpose. It runs in background, and catches the button press events, and you can configure what it will do:

[image: skype call button screenshot]

It integrates with Skype (which will ask you if you authorize this program), so that you can answer an incoming call by pressing the button.