# SkypeCallButton - where is it?

Tags: skype, webcam

> **Related question:**
>   [How can I use the “Windows Live Call Button” on my headphone to answer a call with Skype?](https://superuser.com/questions/151989/how-can-i-use-the-windows-live-call-button-on-my-headphone-to-answer-a-call-wit)

Hi. Gnoupi wrote about this useful utility here; http://www.gooduser.info/entry/ldquo-windows-live-call-button-rdquo-headphone-answer-call-skype.

Unfortunately, while the blog by J. Kay still exists, the download link seems to be broken & he doesn't respond to postings - perhaps he has moved on to other things?

At any rate, if gnoupi or someone else has the utility and wouldn't mind posting it somewhere else (or emailing it) - I'd be grateful as this is exactly what I am looking for.

Thanks,
Yosh

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of "How can I use the “Windows Live Call Button” on my headphone to answer a call with Skype?" - that is precisely the entry I referenced in my post! Please read my post carefully and you will see that I am asking if someone else has a copy of the utility mentioned since the original Blog's link is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the author had some personal issues, which he talks about [here](http://messengergeek.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/updates-links-and-messenger-around-the-web/):

> **Updates**
>   I’d like to apologize for
>   being several weeks behind on
>   comments.  A number of events have
>   happened recently including losing my
>   primary file host, loss of employment
>   and related personal issues.
>
> **Links**
>   Some of the download links were
>   broken since my file hoster (which was
>   kindly hosted by my former employer)
>   no longer exists.  They should be all
>   fixed now and I quickly ran through
>   them all.  If you find a broken one,
>   please let me know.

The [download link](http://messenger.jonathankay.com/redir/skypecallbuttondl.asp) present in the other question is now valid again.

Comment: Thanks, Gnoupi, for taking the trouble to read and answer my question with pertinent info. Glad to hear that meanwhile J. Kay is back online - hope he finds another job soon.